# What tool do you use to do burndown charts?

Tags: project-management, charts

do you use a tool?  or just manually make them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Google charts api/server](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/basics.html) can make one fairly easily

[image: Burndown 2]
[image: Burn down]

You specify everything in the URL so it's easy to update:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
chs=600x250& // the size of the chart
chtt=Burndown& // Title
cht=lc& // The chart type - "lc" means a line chart that only needs Y values
chdl=estimated|actual& // The two legends
chco=FF0000,00FF00& // The colours in hex of the two lines
chxr=0,0,30,2|1,0,40,2& // The data range for the x,y (index,min,max,interval)
chds=0,40 // The min and max values for the data. i.e. amount of features
chd=t:40,36,32,28,24,20,16,12,8,4,0|40,39,38,37,36,35,30,25,23,21,18,14,12,9,1 // Data
```

The URL above plots in intervals of 2 - so work every 2 days. You'll need a bigger size chart for every day. To do this make the data have 30 values for estimated and actual, and change the "chxr" so the interval is 1, not two.

You can plot only the days done more clearly with the "lxy" chart type (the first image). This needs you to enter the X data values too (so a vector). Use -1 for unknown.

Comment: Clever! Note that if you set the y value (in chd) to -1 for "actual", it will not be rendered in the chart. If you just omit future days, the "actual" line will not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

We tend to just use a simple shared excel sheet with a graph on one tab and a pivot table on another.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used myself, but http://apps.vanpuffelen.net/charts/burndown.jsp presents an api that is even simpler than the google charts api. Example:

```
http://apps.vanpuffelen.net/charts/burndown.jsp?days=17,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,29,30&work=125,112,104,99,95
```

gives the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did use TargetProcess but I now prefer a more tactile method so I draw it manually on a whiteboard.

Answer (score 1):

[VersionOne](http://www.versionone.com/) makes the burndown sheets nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Like answered in this post [What tools provide burndown charts to Bugzilla or Mylyn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528519/what-tools-provide-burndown-charts-to-bugzilla-or-mylyn/8736768#8736768)

[www.in-sight.io](http://www.burndown-charts.com/) (previously burndowncharts) is a great SCRUM analytics tool.

Here are some dashboard examples:

[Sprint metrics](http://www.burndown-charts.com/teams/family-petre-bach/sprints/baby-shower)

[Team metrics](http://www.burndown-charts.com/teams/family-petre-bach)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We use something locally based on http://opentcdb.org/ but that does scrum tracking, and draws pretty graphs.

Answer (score 0):

We use the community edition of RallyDev and it makes nice burndown charts.  The problem is that our team has not yet been able to do a solid job of entering in data to keep the burndown information meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

We also use the community edition of [RallyDev](http://www.rallydev.com/) that has nice charts.  I find it to be an excellent tool once you work out which bits of it you really want to use.  There is a huge amount of fields and functionality that most people wouldn't use which could be a confusing problem for bigger teams.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use the tools at rallydev.com, but in time we found the tool to simply be to cumbersome for what we wanted.

In time, I moved to just a simple Excel spreadsheet. Every morning before stand up I counted the hours remaining and added the trend line next to an "ideal" burndown line on the chart. I posted it on the wall where we held our morning standups.

Answer (score 0):

We you Team Foundation Server and with conchango's scrum templates using the built in burndown through this nice little scrum dashboard

http://www.codeplex.com/scrumdashboard

Answer (score 0):

I used google docs and excel.  Templates for both are available at the bottom of this article (and include a number of nice features like automatic calculation of the efficiency factor)

[Burn Down Chart Tutorial: Simple Agile Project Tracking](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/burn-down-charts-tutorial-simple-agile-project-tracking/)