# What tools provide burndown charts to Bugzilla or Mylyn?

Tags: plugins, agile, bugzilla, mylyn

My team and I need to work on a project whose bugs are filed in Bugzilla, using Mylyn.

**Do you know of any tool or plug-in that provides scrum-inspired burndown charts to Bugzilla or Mylyn?**

Hopefully, this tool would be free for commercial usage, but we're not closed to commercial tools.

**Update:** 4 hours of research allowed me to find very few free tools. Looks like bugzilla isn't popular in agile teams! And obviously, it's not the best fit.

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised how alone I'm in doing it. ...Looks like most agile teams are able to use other things than bugzilla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Songbird](http://auberger.com/2008/12/15/songbird-path-to-agility-part-iii/) project made a really good job of documenting how they customized their **Bugzilla** instance and developed tools to automatically generate daily reports, including burndown charts. They released their set of tools as ruby **open-source** code under the MIT license. Very interesting stuff, especially since it comes from a high-profile, important community project.

Answer (score 3):

There's [Scrum Vision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scrumvision/):

- **free**
- **open source** in very active development
- for **mylyn**
- publishes burndown chart to a *Google Spreadsheet*

We think of this as the last resort option, because of the charts being generated offsite.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com/Product/Integration.aspx):

- **commercial**
- **free** for up to 5 persons, self-hosted (need a Windows server)
- integrates with **Bugzilla** and JIRA:

  - **Bugzilla** synchronization is automatic, one-way (read-only)
  - JIRA synchronization is automatic, two-way
  - Subversion, Selenium, and more

Answer (score 3):

And there's [VersionOne](http://www.versionone.com/products_CompareEditions.asp#):

- supposedly the most used **commercial** tool
- integrates with **Bugzilla**, JIRA, Subversion, Fitnesse and more

There's also a really nice [features list (PDF).](http://www.versionone.com/pdf/AgileToolEvaluator.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't easy to find out that [ScrumWorks Pro](http://danube.com/scrumworks/pro/features/integrations) features burndown charts, but on second look, it does:

- **commercial**
- price undisclosed (contact the company for a quote!)
- Pro integrates with **Bugzilla** and JIRA
- synchronization is **manual**: import or update-from-reimport
- synchronization is **one-way**: bugs/issues are read-only in the software

Comment: Their basic edition also offers sprint burndown graphs ; and it's free for commercial usage.

Comment: ...but doesn't include the integrations, if I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

I also found [Rally Enterprise Edition](http://www.rallydev.com/products/editions/).

- **commercial**
- EE integrates with:

  - **Bugzilla** and JIRA:

    - **Bugzilla** synchronization is automatic, two-way
    - JIRA synchronization is manual, two-way
  - **Mylyn** & TaskTop
  - Subversion, Fitnesse, Hudson, Ant, and much more

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Yoxel](http://www.yoxel.com):

- **commercial open-source**
- integrates with **Bugzilla** and others
- not sure if burndown charts are part of the free open-source offering
- UI and UX made it really hard to find burndown charts. Or maybe because the demo data wasn't setup to make them work, because I've definitely seen line charts, just no burndown-looking one.

Answer (score 0):

- Free for commercial use
- Online
- Simple

Have a look:
http://www.burndown-charts.com/teams/dreamteam/sprints/prototype-x

Oh they also support teams in different time zones and openID.